How do different water chemistries harm or protect metals with corrosion and scale?
Question
When re-mineralizing distilled water with some combination of the following minerals, how do different chemistries affect how quickly the water corrodes metals like brass and how much scale builds up at temperatures between 85-130 $^\circ\text{C}$? I'm trying to come up with the best chemistry to protect the metal from corrosion and to protect very very small metal tubes / holes from clogging (with scale) while also keeping the water food safe.
Are there any water chemistries with the minerals listed that would not be corrosive and not deposit any scale? (Or if they would deposit scale, only a very very small amount)
Available minerals for general hardness (GH):

$\text{MgSO}_4 \cdot 7\text{H}_2\text{O}$ (epsom salt)
$\text{CaSO}_4 \cdot 2\text{H}_2\text{O}$ (gypsum)
$\text{CaCl}_2 \cdot 2\text{H}_2\text{O}$

Available minerals for alkalinity (KH):

$\text{NaHCO}_3$ (baking soda)
$\text{KHCO}_3$

For example

Would distilled water with added baking soda for 50 ppm as CaCO3 equivalent (50 KH) be corrosive to brass (maybe via leeching)? Would a small amount of GH be beneficial? (0 GH / 50 KH)

Would 20 GH (from epsom salt) / 50 KH (from baking soda) be less corrosive? Would it form any protective deposits?

What if the GH came from gypsum (20 GH / 50 KH): more or less corrosive? More or less scale?

What if the GH came from calcium chloride instead of sulphates (20 GH / 50 KH): more or less corrosive? More or less scale?


Background
I am adding minerals to distilled water for use in an espresso machine.
I have read numerous blogs about coffee water chemistry but haven't gotten super clear information.
Some people say you need some GH, but it's unclear whether they mean it is required for taste or for the safety of the espresso machine.
Some people say you don't need any GH and the less the better to prevent scale deposits, but those people don't really talk about corrosiveness at all so I wonder if they have considered it.
I also understand that some very small amount of scale deposits can help protect the metal... but I'm trying to figure out what level of which minerals is best to minimize de-scaling maintenance and prevent corrosion. I'm asking here (in a chemistry forum) because I want answers reflecting only the chemistry of how to protect metal from water.

There are tables listing corrosion resistance, such as these from RoyMech and from Special Metals. Search for specific additives, such as "magnesium sulfate" or "MgSO4" *.
That said, you might be overthinking the problem.

Coffee machines are designed to be use in areas where there is naturally hard water, and mildly alkaline or acidic water.
The amount of minerals you propose to add shouldn't exceed what is found naturally, or the product would be unpalatable.

That is not to say there won't be any corrosion. My house is in an area with podzol, making ground water acidic. Copper pipes have slowly corroded, and I've had pinhole leaks from that after many years. After a number of years of heavy use you might need to replace thin parts or tiny orifices -- as would be expected using tap water (Oh! Horrors at the thought ;-).

*  Intentionally, LaTex formula entry was not used for search term.
